# How to rebuild a table in order to free space used by old columns deleted

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a MSSQL clustered index, which I want to rebuild, since I dropped some columns and I want to free space.

In the literature, I have read that, for heaps, you can write

```
ALTER TABLE myHeap REBUILD;
```

And for clustered indexes:

```
ALTER INDEX IX_myIndex ON myTable REBUILD;
```

I have two questions:

1) With the index rebuild, will the space previously used by columns deleted be freed?

2) What happens if I call `ALTER TABLE myHeap REBUILD;` on a clustered table? I tried it and it seems to work, but is this equivalent to writing `ALTER INDEX IX_myIndex ON myTable REBUILD;` ? Or what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

If the columns you have dropped were not any of the blob data types then what you are trying to do should work.

But if any of the columns you have dropper were blob data types (text, ntext, n\varchar(max),xml) then the best way to free up the space would be to

1. Create a new table
2. Populate that table with the data from this old table.
3. Drop the Old table.
4. Rename the New table to Old table.
5. Create Indexes on new table.

In my experience freeing up space once used by blob data types is never a simple and easy task, unless you drop and create tables.

**Important note**

Any table specific permissions for users will be lost so be careful when dropping and creating objects.

Answer (score 1):

When you rebuild a table with clustered index, it'll automatically rebuild the clustered index (clustered index is the table).

See documentation here...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

> REBUILD Use the REBUILD WITH syntax to rebuild an entire table
>   including all the partitions in a partitioned table. If the table has
>   a clustered index, the REBUILD option rebuilds the clustered index.
>   REBUILD can be performed as an ONLINE operation.

Comment: What's the differences with command SHRINKDATABASE and SHRINKFILE ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below SQL command for rebuilding a table with indexes and free space for the same.

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [TABLE NAME] REBUILD;
```