# Why nvarchar takes less storage than decimal in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, decimal, nvarchar

A table has a `nvarchar(12)` column that stores MSISDNs (numbers only of a phone number). The size of the table is 9 Gb.

After changing the type of the column to `decimal(12,0)`, the size of the table becomes 17 Gb.

What is the reason? I thought that `nvarchar(12)` should take more space than `decimal(12,0)`?

Comment: `nvarchar` isn't larger. a `nvarchar(12)` will be 26 bytes in size where as a `decimal(12,0)` would be 9. Most likely the storage engine would have had to rewrite *every* value, meaning that for a short period of time there were 2 copies of the values; the `nvarchar` and the `decimal`, and then the `nvarchar` values were removed. The table, however, won't get smaller as the pages are already written. This is much like when you change something like a `datetime` to a `date`; the latter is smaller in size but until the pages are rewritten the actual space used won't change.

Comment: @Larnu, is there a way to rewrite the pages right after the type will be changed to get smaller database?

Comment: You need to `REBUILD` the table/indexes. There's a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134582/how-to-rebuild-a-table-in-order-to-free-space-used-by-old-columns-deleted)